# Is there a word or expression that describes something that is of little or dubious value but that we are reluctant to let go of?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is one of those words that there is a Chinese word for (雞肋 (jīlè), literal translation - “chicken ribs”) but I cannot find an English equivalent of.

I am trying to find a more succinct way of saying: "If you cannot let go of something, it is probably not worth holding onto." If there is an object or concept that represents this idea, then I can use it instead of this wordy and often misunderstood expression. I think addictions are the best example of things that if you cannot let go of, it is better off not holding onto it at all.

Comment: 'Idol' has one sense of 'something one is excessively devoted to' (hence 'idolatry'), but is highly polysemous.

Comment: Looks like a central tenet of *Eastern* religion / philosophy (that you can only find true peace by letting go of your earthly desires). Western *(Anglophone)* thinking is more like *If you **really want** something, grab it, and never give it up, because **what you want is part of who you are.*** Hence most of our "keepsake, memento, talisman, mascot..." words are positive rather than negative. Maybe Peanuts'  Linus' ***security blanket.***

Comment: Do you just mean something "of little or dubious value," or do you mean something actively harmful like an addiction?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Certainly many Western religious thinkers have also advocated for letting go of earthly desires.

Comment: Nostalgia and sentimentality are relevant words.

Comment: Could be [attachment](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/attachment) that binds you to a one-sided view of it.

Comment: @alphabet I guess value is in the eye of the beholder, but yes I was referring to things of little or dubious value, unless one really enjoys picking out the meat between the chicken ribs. Addiction was probably a bad example since you can be addicted to cheap or expensive things, but my point was to say that addiction can feel like you have an inability to let go of something that you desperately try to cling onto.

Comment: @Xanne I feel like nostalgia and sentimentality are used to describe things that do have value, just not the pecuniary but the emotional kind.

Comment: @MichaelLai Would ["an albatross around one's neck"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/albatross_around_one%27s_neck) fit?